# Using the Potty

Tags: potty-training

My 2 year and 10 month old started to poo into the potty 3 months ago, he would have a bowel movement once a day since then, but it only lasted for 4 days. He now wants his diaper all the time, and he just "dislikes", "refuses", or "hates" when I try to sit him down on the potty. When I asked/said, "let's poop", he hates it!

I started to put just underwear on him yesterday, and of course, he has many accidents, he even poops in the underwear! Should I still put underwear on him? or sit him on the potty frequently? Or should I just still continue with the diapers?

Comment: We have a lot of questions (and answers) about potty training and regression, with questions nearly identical to yours. Did you search the site (with the tag, for instance)? Did it not help you? Is there anything unique to your situation that's not covered in, say, [this question](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/14772/9327) or [this one](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/30711/9327)? (There are many others as well.)